# How can I get blog content from SFTP?

Tags: blog, filesystem, bloginfo, account

I inherited a site that was compromised (I'm not sure what version of wordpress, the crash happened last summer). I have CLI access, and can SFTP into the server. The only thing I want to get is the content of the blogs. I was able to see the mysql files from SFTP, but they are just the .frm files. What is the best way to get this content?

Comment: If you have CLI access, can you use the `mysql` commands or WP CLI?

Comment: i was able to get mysql access!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing since I had Mysql/SFTP access, was:

1. create a dump using these instructions: [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html)
2. get the .sql file using cyberduck(newest version of mac conflicts with filezilla)
3. open a local mysql workbench
4. Run the .sql file
5. using a select, get the blog info I needed

Answer (score 0):

All of WP's blog content is in the database that is used by the blog. The database name is found in the wp-config.php file.

You could do a fresh WP install in a new folder (or new host or new local WP instance), then change the wp-config.php file for the old database : database name, user, password. That won't copy over all of your themes/plugins, although any theme/plugin data stored in the wp-config table will be there if you install/activate the theme.

All of the posts are in the wp-posts table (as well as pages and media), but it's a bit complex to extract posts from the wp-posts table.

If you want to see the site's posts/pages, then the above procedure will get you started.

Comment: thanks! i was able to get a mysql dump and reload it that way

Comment: Glad to know you were successful. (Note that it is 'polite' to reward correct answers with a 'checkmark'. And that lets others know the answer to a similar problem.)

Comment: Your answer wasn't the final soultion, but thank you for it, I'll post what I did. Thanks :)